# Angular App cannot compile after update from V8 to V9

Tags: angular, migration, angular9

I have recently updated my angular app from V8 to V9 using [this guide](https://update.angular.io/#8.2:9.0l2) provided by the official Angular site. I followed all the steps from the guide and the app was successfully updated, but now when I try to build, I get loads of errors related to pipes directives and even components that I am using in my templates.

Here's one example for errors on *pipes*:

> Cannot declare 'TimeAgoPipe' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

Another example of errors on *directives*:

> Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

This code worked perfectly fine on Angular 8:

```
<input required name="password" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="model.password"/>
```

It can't even find *components* that I have created even though they have been declared in the `app.module.ts` file. It's giving me this error:

> 'app-nav' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-nav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-nav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Here's my `app.module.ts` file where everything it is not finding has been included:

```js
    import { BrowserModule, HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { BsDropdownModule, PaginationModule, ButtonsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
    import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
    import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
    import { NgxGalleryModule } from 'ngx-gallery';
    import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';
    import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';
    import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
    import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
    import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './_services/error.interceptor';
    import { MembersListComponent } from './members/members-list/members-list.component';
    import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
    import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
    import { appRoutes } from './routes';
    import { MemberCardComponent } from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { MemberDetailComponent } from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';
    import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
    import { AlertifyService } from './_services/alertify.service';
    import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
    import { MemberDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/member-detail.resolver';
    import { MemberListResolver } from './_resolvers/member-list.resolver';
    import { MemberEditComponent } from './members/member-edit/member-edit.component';
    import { MemberEditResolver } from './_resolvers/member-edit.resolver';
    import { PreventUsavedChangesGuard } from './_guards/prevent-usaved-changes.guard';
    import { DetailCardContentComponent } from './members/detail-card-content/detail-card-content.component';
    import { PhotoEditorComponent } from './members/photo-editor/photo-editor.component';

    export function tokenGetter() {
      return localStorage.getItem(environment.authTokenName);
    }
    @Injectable()
    export class CustomHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
      overrides = {
        pinch: { enable: false },
        rotate: { enable: false }
      };
    }
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        MembersListComponent,
        ListsComponent,
        MessagesComponent,
        MemberCardComponent,
        MemberDetailComponent,
        MemberEditComponent,
        DetailCardContentComponent,
        PhotoEditorComponent,
        TimeAgoPipe,
        DatePipe
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CommonModule,
        BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
        TabsModule.forRoot(),
        BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
        ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        PaginationModule.forRoot(),
        NgxGalleryModule,
        FileUploadModule,
        JwtModule.forRoot({
          config: {
            tokenGetter,
            whitelistedDomains: environment.routesWithAuthorization,
            blacklistedRoutes: environment.routesWithoutAuthorization
          }
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        UserService,
        AlertifyService,
        AuthGuard,
        PreventUsavedChangesGuard,
        MemberDetailResolver,
        MemberListResolver,
        MemberEditResolver,
        ErrorInterceptorProvider,
        { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: CustomHammerConfig }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

## Update

The solution suggested by Instinct and from https://github.com/AndrewPoyntz/time-ago-pipe/issues/33 works. You have to remember to disable AOT compilation on angular.json though

Comment: Did you find out why ?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Updated the question to include the solution

Comment: Try this link, if you didn't to properly updating till v9.
https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0

Comment: @WaqarNaeem that's the one I used. I think most of the issues are from some libraries nor being adapted for Angular 9 yet.

Comment: Disable AOT in angular.json

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like this module isn't updated for Angular 9. I found a workaround here

https://github.com/AndrewPoyntz/time-ago-pipe/issues/33

```
import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';

@Pipe({
    name: 'timeAgo',
    pure: false
})
export class TimeAgoExtendsPipe extends TimeAgoPipe {}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TimeAgoExtendsPipe,
...
```

Comment: The time ago pipe was just an example from many that had issues. In the end, I just decided to stick to Angular 8 for now and try upgrading at a later point in time. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Update: I tried updating again with the suggested fix and everything worked perfectly. I had to disable AOT compilation though

Comment: I think still angular 9 is unstable, so I think migrate the app is not a good option. as @EndiZhupani stick to the angular 8 is the best decision until google solves the problem

Comment: Just finished updating to Angular 9, and I had to choose between disabling AOT or removing TimeAgoPipe. Both options would allow it to compile. It's a personal choice in the end.